# How to use precise Number variables?

Tags: actionscript-3, numbers

I have this variable:

```
var resources:Number = 10;
```

so, i want to decrease this by 0.1 per frame until it comes to 0, and i'm using this to do what i want:

```
if(resources >= 0.1) resources -= 0.1;
```

and it is not decreasing by 0.1 by 0.1
it is decreasing by a higher closest value to 0.1 something like 0.100000000009999 or similiar...

so my "`var resources:Number = 10;`" variable is decreasing like that

```
if(resources >= 0.1) resources -= 0.1; //9.9
if(resources >= 0.1) resources -= 0.1; //9.8
if(resources >= 0.1) resources -= 0.1; //9.7
if(resources >= 0.1) resources -= 0.1; //9.5999999999999999999
if(resources >= 0.1) resources -= 0.1; //9.4999999999999999999
if(resources >= 0.1) resources -= 0.1; //9.3999999999999999988
if(resources >= 0.1) resources -= 0.1; //9.2999999999999888888
```

not absolutelty like that, but so similiar...
and that loop is stopping when "resources" has been 0.99999999, but i need it to be 0

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: i've just decided to use integers because of this doc, thanks :D :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this snippet:

```
function setPrecision(number:Number, precision:int)
{
    precision = Math.pow(10, precision);
    return (Math.round(number * precision) / precision);
}
```

Or AS3 own toPrecision
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Number.html#toPrecision()